# Assembly language not compiling

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

i am trying to complete 80x86 assembly language program that prompts for and inputs the length, width, and height of a box and computes and displays its volume (length * width * height).

I am a beginner so no clue what I am doing wrong

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT

INCLUDE io.h            ; header file for input/output

.STACK 4096

.DATA
Lenght DWORD   ?
Width DWORD  ?
Hight DWORD ?
prompt1 BYTE    "Enter lenght   ", 0
prompt2 BYTE    "Enter width", 0
prompt3 BYTE    "Enter hight", 0
string  BYTE    40 DUP (?)
resultLbl BYTE  "The volume is", 0
res    BYTE    11 DUP (?), 0

.CODE
_MainProc PROC
        input   prompt1, string, 40      ; read ASCII characters
        atod    string          ; convert to integer
        mov     Length, eax    ; store in memory

        input   prompt2, string, 40      ; repeat for second number
        atod    string
        mov     Width, eax


        input   prompt3, string, 40      ; repeat for third number
        atod    string
        mov     Hight, eax




        mov      eax, Length    ; first number to EAX
        mul      eax, Width    ; add second number
        mul      eax, Hight    ; add second number

        dtoa    res, eax        ; convert to ASCII characters
        output  resultLbl, res          ; output label and sum

        mov     eax, 0  ; exit with return code 0
        ret
_MainProc ENDP
END                             ; end of source code
```

These are the errors I get:

```
Description Severity    Code    Project File    Line    Suppression State
missing operand after unary operator    Error   A2081       27  
missing operand after unary operator    Error   A2081       31  
missing operand after unary operator    Error   A2081       41  
syntax error : ,    Error   A2008       42  
syntax error : ,    Error   A2008       43  
syntax error : width    Error   A2008   14  
The command "ml.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"Debug\example.obj" /W3 /errorReport:prompt /Fl /Taexample.asm" exited with code 1.   Error   MSB3721 C:\Users\rzaman\Downloads\AARaianaZaman\solutions\solutions\windows32   70
```

Comment: For one `mul` doesn't take 2 operands.

Comment: Yup, you want `imul eax, Width` for normal integer multiply (not setting EDX to the high half of a full multiply).  (And BTW, typo in your variable name: `Height`, not `Hight`.

Comment: thanks I changed it to imul it is still giving me same errors. Can anyone tell me what i am missing in line 14 which is:                                                         
 Width DWORD  ?                                              
 syntax error : width    Error   A2008   14

Comment: WIDTH and LENGTH are operators in MASM.  You can't use them as the name of labels.

Answer (score 0):

`mul` instruction only takes one argument and the second argument is in the register AL/AX/EAX depending on the size of the argument you passed. Info from Intel instruction manual-[image] 
so following code should work-

`mov      eax, Length    ; first number to EAX
 mul      Width          ; add second number 
 mul      Hight          ; add second number`

Also, if your multiplication result is more than 32-bit then you have to get upper bits of your result from `edx` register.

Comment: Yes this works, but there's no reason to use slower widening full `mul` in 32-bit code unless you actually *want* the high-half result.  The OP's code isn't doing that, so use `imul eax, [Width]`.  `imul reg, reg/mem` is the "normal" multiply instruction most people are looking for, which works like `add reg, reg/mem`.